# Adding and removing textboxes using jquery

Tags: jquery

My requirement is to add two side by side text box Once user click on add hyperlink.After that for that row add link should disappear.
Also clicking on remove must remove only those two textbox which are in the same tr.My code is like this.Its no way complete.But I need suggestions
regarding the implementation.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
 div{
  padding:4px;
 }
</style>

</head>

<body>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;

    $(".addButton").live("click", function () {

 if(counter>5){
            alert("Only 5 textboxes allow");
            return false;
 }   

 var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
      .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

 newTextBoxDiv.html('<TABLE><TR id="'+counter+'"><TD>' +
'<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
'" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" ></TD><TD><input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
'" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" ></TD>&nbsp;<TD><a href="#" value="addButton" class="addButton">Add</a>&nbsp;<a href="#" value="removeButton" class="removeButton">Remove</a></TD></TR></TABLE>');

 newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


 counter++;
     });

     $(".removeButton").live("click", function () {
 if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   

 counter--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

     });

     $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

 var msg = '';
 for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
      msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
 }
       alert(msg);
     });
  });
</script>
</head><body>

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
 <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
  <TR><TD><input type='textbox' id='textbox1' ></TD>&nbsp;<TD><input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
'" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" ></TD>&nbsp;<TD><a href="#" value="addButton" class="addButton">Add</a>&nbsp;<a href="#" value="removeButton" class="removeButton">Remove</a></TD></TR>
 </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your html is horrible:

1. There is no `input type="textbox"` (perhaps you mean `type="text"` or, simply, `textarea`?)
2. Your `tr` seems to have no parent `table` element (a `tr` isn't a valid child of a div, so far as I'm aware, and a `table` is a required parent element of a `tr`).
3. `&nbsp;` shouldn't be appearing between cells,
4. I'm assuming that this was just to demonstrate your working, but the JavaScript variables `id="textbox' + counter + '" value=""` shouldn't be in the html.

However, based on my best guess for what you want to achieve, I can offer this:

#### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('button.add').live('click',
            function(){
                $(this)
                    .closest('tr')
                    .clone()
                    .appendTo('table');
                $(this)
                    .text('Remove')
                    .removeClass('add')
                    .addClass('remove');
            });
        $('button.remove').live('click',
            function(){
                $(this)
                    .closest('tr')
                    .remove();
            });
        $('input:text').each(
            function(){
                var thisName = $(this).attr('name'),
                    thisRrow = $(this)
                                .closest('tr')
                                .index();
                $(this).attr('name', 'row' + thisRow + thisName);
                $(this).attr('id', 'row' + thisRow + thisName);
            });
    });
```

#### html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="col1" id="col1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="col2" id="col2" /></td>
        <td><button class="add">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Demo at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/e5cZR/1/).

This is, of course, a *best-guess* at what you want. If I've misunderstood your requirements, please leave comments and I'll do my best to help out and/or adapt this to be closer to what you need.

Comment: @OddOneOut, you're welcome, glad it was of use to you =)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what's your problem, what errors are you getting? The script is not doing what is supposed to do?

I suggest cleaning your markup in order to make your page at least validate.

Once you have a clearer and valid html the jquery `append` and `remove` syntax is straightforward,
as far as I can see you don't even need a counter here, use jquery selectors to get the DOM state on every user click..

BTW jquery current version is 1.4.4, it's good practice to use always the latest version available.